# Ellipse Geometry Custom Shape

Tags: wpf, geometry, overriding, shapes, ellipse

I am deriving from shape to draw an ellipse. The drawing starts at 0,0 so only the bottom right corner of the ellipse its drawn. How do I transform the origin in the overridegeometry method:

```
class Ellipse2 : Shape
{
    EllipseGeometry ellipse;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxRProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxR", typeof(TextBox), typeof(Ellipse2), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
    public TextBox TextBox
    {
        get { return (TextBox)GetValue(TextBoxRProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBoxRProperty, value); }
    }
    public Ellipse2()
    {
        ellipse = new EllipseGeometry();

        this.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
        this.StrokeThickness = 3;
    }
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            ellipse.RadiusX = this.Width/2;
            ellipse.RadiusY = this.Height/2;

            return ellipse;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using

```
protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry 
{ 
   get 
   { 
   TranslateTransform t = new TranslateTransform(ActualWidth / 2, ActualHeight / 2);        
   ellipse.Transform = t; 
   ellipse.RadiusX = this.ActualWidth/2; 
   ellipse.RadiusY = this.ActualHeight/2; 
   return ellipse; 
   } 
}
```

Another way would be to set the center property of the ellipse I think to the attributes (I haven't tried this yet).

Comment: Please read the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337899.aspx, and then strive to not call new inside the get_DefiningGeometry(). While it is not mandatory, it surely can save you some problems later